# Coldfusion application in subdirectory REST Mapping Issue

Tags: rest, coldfusion

I have an application that when it was in the root of the site worked fine.  I put it in a subdirectory to test compatibility and it breaks.  The structure is as follows:

```
/cfc/
    rest/ -- Rest endpoints
    model/ -- ORM model mappings
    util/ -- some util classes
```

It's a pretty simple crud that also gets the metadata for the models for use in the front end.   Basically, any calls from the rest endpoints or cfc's called from the rest endpoints will encounter an error when it's dealing with anything that requires pathing.  For example:

`getComponentMetaData("models.table");`

errors cannot find componenet models.table.  This is using a mapping to `/cfc/model`, if I try `cfc.model.table`, same thing happens, as well as `ApplicationName.cfc.model.table`.

I have a feeling this is due to how CF is registering the rest endpoints, since it works as a root application, but just stalls out like this when it's in a subdir.  Anyone have any insight on anything that can be done or how CF handles the registration that there might be a work around to it?

Comment: You say, "This is using a mapping to `/cfc/model`." Is this a mapping set in ColdFusion Administrator, or is it in Application.cfc? Please show the mapping definition.

Comment: It was a mapping from the application.cfc.  like this:

`this.mappings["/models"]  = getDirectoryFromPath(getCurrentTemplatePath())&"cfc/model";`

Comment: I think I've found a workaround for it, but it involves basically getting the metadata by using entityNew(modelName); and getMetadata() on the entity instead of using getComponentMetadata.  

I'm still not sure why CF is having issues resolving the pathing for component metadata when used with a REST cfc, but it does work on a normal cfc in the same directory that isn't marked for rest.  For now, I'm fine with my workaround as it's a small application and I can cache the metadata, but it's still a little annoying

Comment: If you dump the meta data, what does it list as the full name of the component?

Comment: main.ApplicationName.cfc.model.TableName

main being at the root of wwwroot, and the rest is pretty explanatory.  Now it does show that name and fullname are the same.  I need to revisit the docs and see if name is something you can specify, I thought that was assigned by CF and displayName was the only one you could change